# Can we have multiple databases in ElastiCache (for Redis)?

Tags: database, redis, amazon-elasticache

Difficult to find this information for ElastiCache (for Redis) - if we can use databases with it such as 0, 1, 2 ... like it's possible in Redis.

Answer (score 4):

We have quite a few ElastiCache instances (standalone) running in AWS and it simply works.
Launch the CLI by issuing command:

```
redis-cli
```

Then use the following command:

```
select <db number>
```

For example:

```
select 4
```

And you'll be working with DB 4, by default you're connected to DB 0.
Redis by default has 16 databases available.

**Edit:** Redis Cluster supports only one database (0).

Comment: Does this work for Muilt AZ Elastic Cache for Redis? I read this warning "When using Redis Cluster, the SELECT command cannot be used, since Redis Cluster only supports database zero" at https://redis.io/commands/select/
Would that limit also apply to Muilt AZ Elastic Cache for Redis?

Comment: @SamAnthony you are correct, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Just to clarify, the SELECT command does work with "Muilt AZ Elastic Cache for Redis", but not for "Redis Cluster" as stated in the documentation.